# How to add a word to a small list value

Tags: python, list, addition

```
list=["Book","Glass","Book,"Watch","Doll,"Book"]
def a_list(list)
```

output:

```
The List is:
Book
Glass
Book
Watch
Doll
Book
```

The List after Check:

```
Book
Glass unique
Book
Watch unique
Doll unique
Book
```

Comment: Can you format your question  a little  better?

Comment: Can someone help me ? please

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry but this is my first time using stack overflow

Comment: You need to edit your question for syntax problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to detect unique items that don't have a count more than 1.

```
from collections import Counter

lst=["Book","Glass","Book","Watch","Doll","Book"]

def a_list(items):

    # Count the words
    counts = Counter(items)

    for item in items:

        # Found a non-unique item, don't add "unique" to it
        if counts[item] > 1:
            print(item)

        # Found a unique item, add "unique" to it
        else:
            print(item, "unique")

a_list(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
Book
Glass unique
Book
Watch unique
Doll unique
Book
```

We can also append these items to a new list and return that as well:

```
def a_list(items):
    counts = Counter(items)

    result = []
    for item in items:
        if counts[item] > 1:
            result.append(item)
        else:
            result.append(f"{item} unique")

    return result

print(a_list(lst))
```

Or using a [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html):

```
def a_list(items):
    counts = Counter(items)
    return [item if counts[item] > 1 else f"{item} unique" for item in items]

print(a_list(lst))
```

**Output:**

```
['Book', 'Glass unique', 'Book', 'Watch unique', 'Doll unique', 'Book']
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach to do so is:

```
ll=["Book","Glass","Book","Watch","Doll","Book"]
def a_list(l):
    for elem in l:
        if l.count(elem) > 1:
            print(elem)
        else:
            print(elem, "unique")

a_list(ll)
```

This will give the desired output.

If you want to alter the list and return it, the same logic should be used but instead of printing you should change the element itself as follows:

```
ll=["Book","Glass","Book","Watch","Doll","Book"]
def a_list(l):
    for i, elem in enumerate(l):
        if l.count(elem) > 1:
            l[i] = "{:} unique".format(elem)
    return l

lll = a_list(ll)
print(lll)
```